# Jenkins + Klocwork Community Plugin Incremental Analysis

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, klocwork

We are having an issue with our Jenkins setup and i am not sure why as it seemed to work in the past but here is what is happening.

We run our build using kwinject, get our .out file, in the KW Plugin we create a diff file against our parent commit to get our diffs_file.txt containing all the files that were changed in the current commit on gerrit.

This all works, the problem is that there are commits that are modifying nothing but files related to our build process, linux makefiles, python scripts,etc.  So all of these files are in the diffs_files.txt, but obviously arent in our KW Build specification file because they arent actually 'built'.

This results in kwcheck run returning an error code 1 saying there are no files to analyse, which halts any remaining steps in our build process.

I'm a bit at a loss why its returning error code 1 if none of the files in the diff_files.txt are in the build specification.

Answer (score 0):

When you see "there are no files to analyse" message, that means the .OUT file has not been generated properly. You can open the .OUT file and look for config: and compile: options/lines.

Here is the procedure to deal with incomplete Klocwork build spec files, https://docs.roguewave.com/en/klocwork/current/troubleshootinganincompletekwinjectbuildspecification

if it doesn't help, please feel free to reach Klocwork support.